# Print external page using window.print()

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, printing

So right now I have a function that opens a window and loads a shipping label. I then right click and select to print and then go through the chrome print window.

My code right now:

```
function printLabel(){

   window.open('<?php echo $order->shipmentLabel; ?>', 'name', 'width=800, height=400');

   return false;
}
```

This works okay. But what I really want to do is once the `printLabel` function is called to have the `<?php echo $order->shipmentLabel; ?>` automatically print to my default printer. With even skipping the chrome print page.

How could I do that?

This webpage that does this action will only ever be accessed by one computer and only by me so if settings must be changed in chrome to allow this, that is completely plausible.

**If skipping the Google Chrome print window is NOT an option, I still need to know how to load an external page for printing without opening it.**

Comment: Not sure if that's possible, but I would think that would be more of an operating system / Chrome configuration approach than something you can solve programmatically with JavaScript.

Comment: If you're expecting Chrome to handle the printing you're likely to have to live with the Print window, and there's no way I can think of to print a document you haven't opened. If you have a network capable printer you could perhaps have PHP print directly to it, bypassing Chrome altogether, but that would require a different rendering process.

Comment: @MikeW have an HP OfficeJet 4622 that is wireless, So would PHP printing work with that?

Comment: @user3367639 If you can set the printer up as a printer for the server you're using to create the pages then potentially yes. Doing that and then reworking your PHP to print to it are wholly different questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called silent printing.

Here a tutorial:
http://drziegler.net/kiosksilent-printing-in-google-chrome/

Comment: Every time I try to add `--kiosk --kiosk-printing` to the end of the target field, I get that it is an `invalid target path`. I am using windows 8

Comment: Ha! Figured it out. That is pretty awesome. But how do I print an external page. All it really is a `.png`